# Reading string with Jquery and changing check-box status according to string

Tags: jquery

I have an organized table displaying user's favorite days of the week.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4wGG/1/

A pop-up div screen will present itself when you click on a row to edit.
What I am trying to do is read the content of the column "Days" and check the boxes inside the pop-up screen that correlate to the string.

```
M = Monday
T = Tuesday
W = Wednesday
Th = Thursday
F = Friday
```

Example: M,W,F = Monday,Wednesday,Friday

The symbols will always be comma delimited. In this example, the checkboxes next to M, W, and F will be checked.

format

```
<label for="new_friday">F</label> &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" id="new_friday" name="f" value="f"> &nbsp;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the liberty of refactoring most of your code. Hope it helps

```
// These elements don't change so no point getting them on each click
var modal = $('#transparent').on('click.close', function() {
        $(this).hide(); // hide the element on click
    }),
    username_input = modal.find('input[name=username]'),
    email_input = modal.find('input[name=email]'),
    day_checkboxes = modal.find('input[type=checkbox]');

$('#close').on('click', function() {
    modal.trigger('click.close'); // trigger the "close" click event
});
$('#splash').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // don't allow clicks to leave the #splash element
});

$('.data').on('click', function(e) {
    // Get all the data from within this element (row)
    var row = $(this),
        username = row.find('.row_user').text(),
        email = row.find('.row_email').text(),
        days = row.find('.row_days').text().toLowerCase();

    // split the days by comma, defaulting to an empty array
    days = days.length && days.split(',') || [];

    modal.show();
    username_input.val(username);
    email_input.val(email);

    day_checkboxes.prop('checked', function() {
        // looks for the "value" in the days array and sets the "checked" property
        return ~days.indexOf(this.value);
    });
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Y4wGG/7/

Comment: I certainly appreciate your efforts and definitely do not understand :D lol

Comment: @MarquézSantos don't let it stop you from learning new stuff!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your function, preferably after the part where you copy the username and email field:

```
var days = $('#' + id + ' .row_days').text().toLowerCase().split(',');

$('#splash input:checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', 
        $.inArray($(this).val(), days) >= 0
    );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4wGG/5

Answer (score 0):

this is your answer, just add the below code after email bit.

```
        var days = $(this).find("td.row_days").text().toLowerCase().split(",");
        $.each(days, function () {
            alert(this);
            $("input[name='"+this+"']").attr("checked", "checked");
        });
```

Comment: I assume you are asking for it does not uncheck the box once checks it pretty sure resetting would not be a problem.